# How To Auto Select First Child Product for swatch with image in list Of Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, color-swatches, configurable-swatches

How To Auto Select First Child Product for swatch with image in list Of Magento 2?

i have override module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js/SwatchRenderer.js
And update the method _RenderControls.
but after this solution auto select color and images of product showing at product view page.
not showing first child color swatch image in list page

what should i do for solution?

Answer (score 0):

override this file

**/module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js/SwatchRenderer.js**

update the method _RenderControls

```
_RenderControls: function () {
    var $widget = this,
        container = this.element,
        classes = this.options.classes,
        chooseText = this.options.jsonConfig.chooseText,
        selectedArray = []; // Variable declation for autoselect element array

    $widget.optionsMap = {};

    $.each(this.options.jsonConfig.attributes, function () {
        var item = this,
            controlLabelId = 'option-label-' + item.code + '-' + item.id,
            options = $widget._RenderSwatchOptions(item, controlLabelId),
            select = $widget._RenderSwatchSelect(item, chooseText),
            input = $widget._RenderFormInput(item),
            listLabel = '',
            label = '';

        // Show only swatch controls
        if ($widget.options.onlySwatches && !$widget.options.jsonSwatchConfig.hasOwnProperty(item.id)) {
            return;
        }

        if ($widget.options.enableControlLabel) {
            label +=
                '<span id="' + controlLabelId + '" class="' + classes.attributeLabelClass + '">' +
                    item.label +
                '</span>' +
                '<span class="' + classes.attributeSelectedOptionLabelClass + '"></span>';
        }

        if ($widget.inProductList) {
            $widget.productForm.append(input);
            input = '';
            listLabel = 'aria-label="' + item.label + '"';
        } else {
            listLabel = 'aria-labelledby="' + controlLabelId + '"';
        }

        // Create new control
        container.append(
            '<div class="' + classes.attributeClass + ' ' + item.code + '" ' +
                 'attribute-code="' + item.code + '" ' +
                 'attribute-id="' + item.id + '">' +
                label +
                '<div aria-activedescendant="" ' +
                     'tabindex="0" ' +
                     'aria-invalid="false" ' +
                     'aria-required="true" ' +
                     'role="listbox" ' + listLabel +
                     'class="' + classes.attributeOptionsWrapper + ' clearfix">' +
                    options + select +
                '</div>' + input +
            '</div>'
        );

        $widget.optionsMap[item.id] = {};

        // Aggregate options array to hash (key => value)
        $.each(item.options, function () {
            if (this.products.length > 0) {
                $widget.optionsMap[item.id][this.id] = {
                    price: parseInt(
                        $widget.options.jsonConfig.optionPrices[this.products[0]].finalPrice.amount,
                        10
                    ),
                    products: this.products
                };
            }
        });
        //Create array for Autoselect swatch
        selectedArray.push($widget.element.find('[attribute-id=' + item.id + '] .swatch-option')[0]);
    });


    // Connect Tooltip
    container
        .find('[option-type="1"], [option-type="2"], [option-type="0"], [option-type="3"]')
        .SwatchRendererTooltip();

    // Hide all elements below more button
    $('.' + classes.moreButton).nextAll().hide();

    // Handle events like click or change
    $widget._EventListener();

    // Rewind options
    $widget._Rewind(container);

    //Emulate click on all swatches from Request
    $widget._EmulateSelected($.parseQuery());
    $widget._EmulateSelected($widget._getSelectedAttributes());

    //Trigger click for Autoselect first option swatch
    $.each(selectedArray, function () {
        if(this != undefined) this.click();
    });

},
```